# How do I make Algolia Search guaruntee that it will return a number of results

Tags: algolia

I need Algolia to always return me 5 results from a full text search even if the query text itself bears little or no relevance to the actual returned results. Before someone suggests it, I have already tried to set the `removeWordsIfNoResults` option to all of it's possible modes and this still doesn't guarantee that I get my 5 results.

The purpose of this is to create a 'relevant entities' sidebar where the name of the current entity is used to search for other entities.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `removeWordsIfNoResults=allOptional` query parameter is indeed a good way to go -> because all query words are required to match an object by default, **fallbacking to "optional"** is a good way to still retrieve results if one you the query words (or the combination of words) doesn't match anything.

```
index.search(query, { removeWordsIfNoResults: 'allOptional' });
```

Another solution is to always consider **all query words as optional** (not only as a fallback); to make sure the query `foo bar baz` is interpreted as `OPT(foo) AND OPT(bar) AND OPT(baz)` <=> `foo OR bar OR baz`. The difference is that this query will retrieve more results than the previous one because 1 single matching word will be enough to retrieve the object.

```
index.search(query, { optionalWords: query });
```

That being said, there is no way to force the engine to retrieve "at least" 5 results. What I would recommend is to have a small frontend logic:
 - do the query with `removeWordsIfNoResults` or `optionalWords`
 - if the engines returns less than 5 results, do another query